# Angular2 cannot match any routes after bundling IE

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-10

I'm having issue with my app after bundling I keep getting this error when I try to open it on the browser.

```
ERRORError: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL 
Segment: 'Demo/ng2'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'Demo/ng2'
   at Anonymous function
```

My router is pretty straight forward so not sure what's wrong with it.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: CatalogsComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];

// - Updated Export
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

and inside `CatalogsComponent` its just a simple HTTP request.

```
constructor(
    public http: Http,
    public dataService: DataService,
    public router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getData()
      .subscribe(data => {
        // if (this.router.url == '') {
        //   this.catalog = true;
        // }

        this.itemData = data.Category;
      })
  }
```

Can someone point out the mistake? Trying to open the app using this URL `http://site-demo/Demo/ng2` its hosted on IIS.

Comment: Is `Demo/ng2` the default base href? If so, you must specify it on production build.

Comment: Yes I have specify it `ng --prod --base-href Demo/ng2`, I even changed it on index.html manually and still showing the same error.

Comment: Does it happens only in IE (10)?

Comment: yeah just breaks on IE, works okay on chrome though. I've changed the basehref to `./` and loads fine on chrome still but not IE

Comment: Nvm looks like its working again, its IE cache issue -.-

Comment: Ah nope not cache -.- broken again >.<